# Use multiple CSVs out a folder individually and save their names

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a directory with a lot of .csv Files, and have to do a command with each of them. While I have to do that I also need to save each of their names corresponding to on which file the action is taken. (like when the first file fires, I give out all the content of one .csv file into a txt and want the "title" in the .txt to be the filename)?

Also, I don't want this:

```
Import-Csv -Path (Get-ChildItem -Path C:\PathToFolder\ -Filter '*.csv').FullName
```

This code would just give me everything in the CSVs as one, but I want to do something with each of them individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Process the output of `Get-ChildItem` in a loop, e.g.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\PathToFolder -Filter '*.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    Import-Csv $_.FullName | ...
}
```